# How To Use SQL Databases on Mac (Without Extra Software)

Tags: sql, database, macos, automator

Hello. I am trying to figure out how to make an SQL database (by using Automator) on my school-owned Mac.

I saw three actions in Automator involving SQL - "Apply SQL" ('This action applies the input SQL against an SQLite database and produces output in one of several formats'), "Convert CSV to SQL" ('This action converts comma-separated value (CSV) input to SQL suitable for application to a database'), and "Execute SQL" ('This action executes some SQL against an SQLite database and produces output in one of several formats').

Can I use these three actions to create, add columns/rows to, update, and retrieve data from an SQL database without using any additional software (like FileMaker)? And, if I can, how do I: a) create the database and, b) run SQL against the database?

Thank you for your help! Please tell me if I was unclear or if this is a duplicate question (I couldn't find anything very similar).

I can only use default software because my school laptop doesn't allow me to download extra applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absolute simplest method to utilize SQL on the Mac is via SQLite, which is built into every Mac.  You launch the Terminal application, and you have instant command line access.  [Look here](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html)

Comment: That is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for, thanks!